# Where to place a little demo for a subproject in Gradle's "Standard Directory Layout"?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a larger Gradle project with several subprojects.
One subproject called "my-little-subproject" is completely independent from all other (sub)projects.
In this "my-little-subproject" I want to add a litte demo (just a handful of Java classes) which shall be build by a Gradle task "buildMyLittleDemo" into directory `my-little-subproject/build/my-little-demo`.
This little demo is only needed for development.
Where exactly do I have to place the ".java" files for the little demo to satisfy the Gradle guidelines? I first thought maybe in a `my-little-subproject/buildSrc/main/java` directory, but this does not seem to work. `my-little-subproject/src/main/java` and `my-little-subproject/src/test/java` do not seem to be right places for the little demo, I guess.

Maybe as a subproject of "my-little-subproject"?

Answer (score 0):

A gradle subproject is required to be declared in settings.gradle file.
so your settings.gradle file should have this line `include 'my-little-subproject'`.
Also each subproject should have its own build.gradle file.